# Behaviour of $this variable in PHP

Tags: php

Why does PHP allow you to do this:

```
<?php

class Doge
{
    public function dogeMember()
    {
        echo "Hello From Doge\r\n";
        $this->nonDogeMember();
    }
}

class DogeCoin extends Doge
{
    public function nonDogeMember()
    {
        echo "Hello from DogeCoin\r\n";
    }
}

$d = new DogeCoin;
$d->dogeMember();
```

Apparently, from the [opcode](http://3v4l.org/k7i7m/vld#tabs), the `$this` variable is ignored and the call is made as if the method were on the `DogeCoin` class.

Comment: Yes, it will be.... you're instantiating the DogeCoin class, so that's what your instance ($this when referenced internally) is, and it will contain the methods that are defined in both Doge and in DogeCoin because that's what extending a class does

Comment: I understand this, but I'm curious as to why `$this` is allowed to refer to a method that doesn't exist in Doge. Is this common to all interpreted languages?

Comment: The method exists by inheritance in the class that you've instantiated.... it's nothing to do with interpreted languages (note that PHP is ___not___ an interpreted language, and ___is___ a compiled language), and everything to do with OOP

Comment: For the same reason that a pit bull can bark. Because a pit bull, while not titled "dog" is a dog. `$this->nonDogeMember` is the same as `pit bull -> bark()` because `bark` is a function of a dog

Comment: @MarkBaker My actual question is the behaviour of `$this` in Class `Doge`. Why does it compile even though `nonDogeMember` doesn't exist in Doge? Is there any other language that allows using the `this` variable in this way?

Comment: It compiles as valid because the test for existence of the method is a run-time test, not a compile-time test.... `$this` is an instance reference, and instances only exist at run-time (when you code has instantiated them) not at compile time, so the code can only know if the method exists when it is actually executing

Comment: Okay, this confirms my first assumption. Since `$this` is evaluated at runtime, does this mean that `$this` at runtime refers to the `$d` and not actually Doge? If so, is this really a good language design?

Comment: Inside the instance, `$this` refers to itself and that approach is pretty much universal in all OOP languages.... if you don't think that it's good design, then perhaps you should take a different approach to coding, such as functional

Comment: There is an aspect of this which is not universal in OOP languages, which is that PHP doesn't try to determine the *type* of `$this` until runtime. In a stricter type system like Java's, the compiler would reject the call because the equivalent of `$this` is known only to be an instance of `Doge` or one of its sub-classes, and the method `nonDogeMember` is not guaranteed to exist on all such instances. PHP's compiler is happy to leave this decision until run-time.

Comment: This is perfectly good design. One thing that may be appropriate for you to add (depending on your intended design approach) is to make class `Doge` abstract and declare `nonDogeMember` inside it as abstract. That way it will be impossible to instantiate the parent on its own, or a child that does not fulfill the abstract method requirement.

Answer (score 2):

In one sentence: `$this` is a reference to the **current object instance**.
An object is/may be composed of several things, including methods and properties of several inherited classes, traits and dynamically added members. Only the "composite" result of all inheritance and dynamic modification during runtime is what makes up the final object instance.

The actual call `$this->nonDogeMember()` is only resolved at runtime. Since the object it's being called on (`$d`) has that method (through inheritance), everything's fine.

Having said that, you *should* not write this kind of code, because there indeed is no guarantee that this method will exist at runtime and may produce a runtime error. To avoid this, you should define your class and that method as abstract:

```
abstract class Doge {

    public function dogeMember() {
        echo "Hello From Doge\r\n";
        $this->nonDogeMember();
    }

    abstract public function nonDogeMember();

}
```

This is PHP's way to help you ensure such runtime errors won't happen, or at least they'll be caught at an earlier point in (run)time and produce an easier to trace error.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual on [Late Static Bindings ¶](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

> In non-static contexts, the called class will be the class of the
>   object instance. Since $this-> will try to call private methods from
>   the same scope, using static:: may give different results. Another
>   difference is that static:: can only refer to static properties.

The Manual goes on to provide the following example.

```
class A {
    public function test() {
        $this->foo();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function foo() {
        echo "Im in B\n";
    }
}

$c = new B();
$c->test();   
$a = new A();
$a->test();
```

Output.

```
Im in B
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method A::foo() in ...
```

Yes, PHP allows this type of behaviour. Should you use it? No.

Comment: Erm... explain please why shouldn't you use polymorphic calls?

Comment: I was originally the quoting the code from the manual on `Example #3 static:: usage in a non-static context`, a fact I made explicit. I have pared the example down to pretty must he code in the question.

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm not saying you should not use polymorphic calls. Just don't reference $this to members not in the parent or your own class.

Comment: This is all a bit misleading / off-topic, because the code in the question doesn't use a static call, it uses an instance call with `$this`.

Comment: There is an expert in the linked doc page explaining why late static binding is named as such, I will add it to the answer when I get home.

Comment: @robbmj: Regardless, the problem in the question has nothing to do with Late Static Binding. The fault lies with the manual itself, which has bundled everything together into the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

When you extend the Doge class you are inheriting all of it's other methods and properties. If you don't want that dogeMember() method to be in your child class, set both classes to extend some other class - maybe an abstract class.

```
class DogeCoin
{
public function dogeMember()
{
    echo "Hello From Doge\r\n";
    $this->nonDogeMember();
}

public function nonDogeMember()
{
    echo "Hello from DogeCoin\r\n";
}
}
```